# Boost asio run vs work (ambiguity) - what's the purpose of the work class?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

As you can see here in this example [UDP server](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6.html), the run method will keep the application running forever. (tested)

So there is no need to use the work class as mentioned in the documentation

From boost documentation:
The work class is used to inform the `io_service` when work starts and finishes. This ensures that the `io_service` object's `run()` function will not exit while work is underway, and that it does exit when there is no unfinished work remaining.

Comment: There is no need in _this example_. This doesn't mean that its never needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `work` class is deprecated and has been replaced by `executor_work_guard`. Its purpose has been explained in the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html#boost_asio.reference.io_context.stopping_the_io_context_from_running_out_of_work):

> Some applications may need to prevent an io_context object's `run()` call from returning when there is no more work to do. For example, the io_context may be being run in a background thread that is launched prior to the application's asynchronous operations. The `run()` call may be kept running by creating an object of type `boost::asio::executor_work_guard<io_context::executor_type>` [...]